# Adding a share button for a mobile site

Tags: html, facebook, share

I want to add a share button for my mobile site, and I need the sharing properties to be custom.

Is there a way I can share a link with custom title, description or comments?

Is there a way to share it through the Facebook mobile application if the user is connected through it?

I've tried to use

```
<a title="send to Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&
p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"    
target="_blank"><span><img width="14" height="14" src="'icons/fb.gif" alt="Facebook" /> 
Facebook></a>
```

It does work with regular sites, but when trying to run it in my mobile, it doesn't share the same...

Comment: if u feel an answer has helped you solve this, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround for this - Make the Facebook share URL go to a page that redirects to the page that you are having trouble with. The redirect page can have new title, meta description and other meta tags in it that you can customize to make the Fb share look just the way you want it. As an example, the QR code on this page takes your phone to the Facebook share link I designed using this technique. I also made a share link for desktops by clicking on the postcard: http://modernmancaves.com/share.html. Side note: This example page does not redirect (so that you have time to try the QR code, mobile share link and view the page's source code)

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the feed dialog on mobile devices (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ )

This allows you to specify the share metadata, and should automatically display a mobile-friendly version on mobile devices

Comment: is there a way to share feeds throw the facebook mobile application if existed in the user's mobile phone ?

Comment: You could copy/paste a link into the Facebook app if that's what your asking, but i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: what i mean that if the user have a facebook mobile application in his cell phone, it will open the link and add the feed dialog throw it. i trying to avoid from opening the link in the mobile web browser because i think most people use facebook for mobile application and i want the link to be open there..